# Expectation value of $\cos^2\theta$ with Associated Legendre Polynomials as basis

Tags: legendre-polynomials

I am trying to solve this integral

$$\int_0^\pi P^m_p(\cos\theta) ~~\cos^2\theta ~~P^m_q(\cos\theta)~~\sin\theta d\theta$$
where $P$ is the Associated Legendre polynomial

*I tried to solve* it by the fact that

$$\cos^2\theta = \frac{2}{3}P^0_2(\cos\theta)+\frac{1}{3}$$
but this gives an integral that consists three Associated Legendre polynomial and I am not sure if this integral has straightforward solution.

This should give three terms that relate $(p,p)$, $(p,p+2)$ and $(p,p-2)$.

Comment: $m$ is a power and $p$ the $p$-th Legendre polynomial?

Comment: @sinbadh No. Associated Legendre polynomials have one two indices, upper and lower.

Comment: Then, what does it mean $P_p^m$?

Comment: @sinbadh Please see for the meaning of m and p:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_Legendre_polynomials